# Error parsing XML: junk after document element;The markup in the document following the root element must be well- formed

Tags: android, xml

I am getting this error:

Multiple annotations found at this line: - The markup in the document following the root element must be well- formed. - error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element

This appears on the beginning of

```
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
    parent="@style/TextAppearane.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs text styles -->
<style name="MyActionBarTabText"
    parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>
```

I accept any help!!

Comment: This is only an XML fragment. We'd probably need the whole document or at least a bigger block of XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Problem is : you forget xmls schema at first line of style.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="@style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar title text -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
        parent="@style/TextAppearane.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar tabs text styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTabText"
        parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: While not declaring the namespace prefix is a real problem that should be corrected, it would not be the cause of *The markup in the document following the root element must be well- formed* error message in most XML parsers.